$\operatorname{argmin}(f_n)\to \operatorname{argmin}(f)$ if $f_n\to f$ uniformly
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb R$ be a compact interval and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function with a unique minimizer such that$$x_0:=\operatorname{argmin}(f)\in X$$
is well-defined. Now let $(f_n)_n$  be a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Since $f_n$ may have several minimizers, we define
$\operatorname{argmin}(f_n)$ to be the maximum of all the minimizers. (I guess that the existence of the maximum is an additional assumption.) That being said, I need to prove that
$$\operatorname{argmin}(f_n)\to \operatorname{argmin}(f)=x_0.$$
Fix $\epsilon >0$. By uniform convergence, for all sufficiently large $n$,
$$f(x_0)-\epsilon\leq \min_{x\in X}f_n(x)\leq f(x_0)+\epsilon$$
and therefore
$$\operatorname{argmin}(f_n)\in\{x\in X:f(x_0)-\epsilon\leq f(x)\leq f(x_0)+\epsilon\}=:X_\epsilon.$$
I expect that

the set $X_\epsilon$ is an interval (necessarely compact and containing $x_0$) for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and
the length of $X_\epsilon$ converges to zero.

Note that proving the last two points would solve the problem. In fact I have an explicit expression for $f$, namely $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+(1-x)^2$ and in view of the graph the last two claims seem obvious, but I am struggling to get a rigorous proof. Can someone help?

$X_\epsilon$ is clearly a compact neighborhood of $x_0$ but its diameter generally doesn't tend to $0$ (it can even be constant).

@AnneBauval, why does not its diameter tend to $0,?;$ The function $f$ is continuous and has a unique minimizer $x_0$ which implies that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x\in X\land x\neq x_0$.

Sorry, you are right, I overlooked that assumption

@Filippo, I have proved that there exists $,\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\mathrm{diam},X_\varepsilon=0,.;$ Are you interested in it ? If yes, I will write the proof as an answer.

@Angelo Do you mean that you have improved Fred's result by showing that $X_\epsilon$ is connected? If yes, I am interested

@Filippo, No, I have just proved that the length or the diameter of $X_\epsilon$ converges to $0$. If you are interested in it, I will write an answer.

@Angelo I think that Fred already proved that the length converges to zero, but if you have a different proof, I am interested to see it

@Filippo, I have found  a continuous function on a compact interval $X$ which has a unique minimizar $x_0$ such that $X_\varepsilon$ is not connected for infinite positive values of $\varepsilon$ that tend to $0$. Hence, in general, it is not true that $X_\epsilon$ is connected. If you want, I will write an answer about it and about $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\mathrm{diam},X_\varepsilon=0,.;$

@Angelo That's sounds interesting! I decided to ask a new question for this purpose: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4962150/572841

Since you assume $f_n$ is continuous, the set of minimizing inputs to $f_n$ is closed and thus compact, so it automatically has a maximum value.

@DanielSchepler Very nice comment, thank you!

I don't think you need $X_\varepsilon$ to be an interval : it is indeed compact so you have $a_\varepsilon=\min(X_\varepsilon)\in X_\varepsilon$ and $b_\varepsilon=\max(X_\varepsilon)\in X_\varepsilon$. For a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$ decreasing to zero you have $a_{\varepsilon_n}\leqslant \text{argmin}(f_n)\leqslant b_{\varepsilon_n}$ and  $f(x_0)-\varepsilon_n\leqslant f(a_{\varepsilon_n}),f(b_{\varepsilon_n})\leqslant f(x_0)+\varepsilon_n$ : $(a_{\varepsilon_n})$, $(b_{\varepsilon_n})$ are monotone convergent sequences to respectively $a$ and $b$, passing to the limit yields $f(a)=f(b)=f(x_0)$ so $a=b=x_0$ so it seems that $\text{argmin}(f_n)\rightarrow x_0$

Awesome, thanks!

Let $y_0:=f(x_0)$.

$X_\epsilon=f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,y_0+\epsilon\right]\right)$ is not necessarily an interval (and we don't care), but is (obviously) a compact neighborhood of $x_0$, as you first wrote.
Let us prove by contradiction that its diameter tends to $0$ with $\epsilon$ i.e. that
$$\forall\delta>0\quad\exists n\in\Bbb N\quad\forall x\in X_{1/n}\quad|x-x_0|<\delta.$$ Assuming the contrary, we get the existence of some positive $\delta$ and some sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad f(x_n)\le y_0+1/n\ \text{ and }\ |x_n-x_0|\ge\delta.$$
Since $X$ is compact, $(x_n)$ has at least one accumulation point $x$, which then satisfies:
$$f(x)\le y_0\ \text{ and }\ |x-x_0|\ge\delta.$$
This contradicts the uniqueness of the minimizer $x_0$, which ends the proof.


Nice answer! I have not proved it by contradiction but through a direct proof.

We are going to prove that there exists $\,\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\mathrm{diam}\,X_\varepsilon=0\,.$
Let $\;x_1\in X\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}\,$ and let $\,\alpha=\left|x_1-x_0\right|>0\,.$
For any $\,\mu>0\,$ we consider $\,\sigma_\mu=\!\!\min\limits_{x\in X\setminus A_\mu}\!\!\left\{f(x)\right\}-f(x_0)\,$ where $\;A_\mu=\left(x_0\!-\!\min\left\{\frac\mu3,\alpha\right\},x_0\!+\!\min\left\{\frac\mu3,\alpha\right\}\right)\,$ is an open interval containing $\,x_0\,$ and $\,X\setminus A_\mu\,$ is a compact subset of $\,X\setminus\left\{x_0\right\}\,$ which is not empty because $\,x_1\in X\setminus A_\mu\,.$
Note that $\min\limits_{x\in X\setminus A_\mu}\!\!\left\{f(x)\right\}\,$ exists because the function $\,f\,$ is continuous on the compact non-empty set $\,X\setminus A_\mu\,.$
It results that $\;\sigma_\mu>0\;$ because $\;x_0\;$ is the unique minimizer of the function $\,f\,,\,$ so $\,f(x)>f(x_0)\,$ for any $\,x\in X\setminus A_\mu\;$ and $\min\limits_{x\in X\setminus A_\mu}\!\!\left\{f(x)\right\}>f(x_0)\,.$
For any $\,\varepsilon\in\left(0,\sigma_\mu\right)\,$ it results that $\,X_\varepsilon\subseteq A_\mu\,$ indeed $\,x^*\!\in X_\varepsilon\,$ implies that $\,x^*\!\in X\,$ and $\,f(x^*)\leqslant f(x_0)+\varepsilon< f(x_0)+\sigma_\mu=\!\!\min\limits_{x\in X\setminus A_\mu}\!\!\left\{f(x)\right\}\,,\,$ that is , $\,f(x^*)<\!\!\min\limits_{x\in X\setminus A_\mu}\!\!\left\{f(x)\right\}\,,\,$ hence , $\;x^*\!\not\in X\setminus A_\mu\,$ which implies that $\,x^*\!\in A_\mu\,.$
So for any $\,\varepsilon\in\left(0,\sigma_\mu\right)\,$ it results that
$0\leqslant\mathrm{diam}\,X_\varepsilon\leqslant\mathrm{diam}\,A_\mu=2\min\left\{\frac\mu3,\alpha\right\}\leqslant2\!\cdot\!\frac\mu3<\mu\,.$
We have proved that for any $\,\mu>0\,$ there exists $\,\sigma_\mu>0\,$ such that for any $\,\varepsilon\in\left(0,\sigma_\mu\right)\,$ it results that $\,0\leqslant\mathrm{diam}\,X_\varepsilon<\mu\,,\,$ that is , there exists
$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\mathrm{diam}\,X_\varepsilon=0\,.$

There exists a continuous function $\,f\,$ on a compact interval $\,X\,$ which has a unique minimizer $\,x_0\,$ such that $\,X_\varepsilon\,$ is not connected for infinite positive values $\,\varepsilon_n\,$ of $\,\varepsilon\,$ that tend to $\,0\,$.
Let $\,f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R\,$ the continuous function on the compact interval $\,X=[-1,1]\,$ defined as follows
$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\!\left[\sin^2\!\!\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\!+1\right]&\text{for any }x\in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}\\[3pt]0&\text{for }x=0\end{cases}$
The function $\,f(x)\,$ has a unique minimizer which is $\,x_0=0\,$ indeed $\,f(x_0)=f(0)=0\,$ and $\,f(x)>0\,$ for any $\,x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}=[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}\,.$
Let $\;\varepsilon_n=\dfrac1{4\pi^2n^2}>0\,.\quad\big(\implies\varepsilon_n\to0\;\;\text{as }\,n\to\infty\big)$
Now we are going to prove that $X_{\varepsilon_n}$ is not connected for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,.$
For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;$ let $\;x’_n=\dfrac1{\frac\pi2\!+\!2n\pi}\in(0,1)\;$ and $\;x’’_n=\dfrac1{2n\pi}\in(0,1)\;.$
It results that $\;0<x’_n<x’’_n\;$ and
$f(x’_n)\!=\!\dfrac2{\left({\frac\pi2\!+\!2n\pi}\right)^2}\!=\!\dfrac2{\pi^2\!\left(2n\!+\!\frac12\right)^2}\!=\!\dfrac2{\pi^2\!\!\left(4n^2\!\!+\!2n\!+\!\frac14\right)}\!>$
$>\dfrac2{\pi^2\!\big(4n^2\!+\!2n\!+\!2n\big)}=\dfrac2{\pi^2\!\big(4n^2\!+\!4n\big)}\geqslant\dfrac2{\pi^2\!\big(4n^2\!+\!4n^2\big)}=$
$=\dfrac1{4\pi^2\!n^2}=0+\dfrac1{4\pi^2\!n^2}=f(0)+\varepsilon_n\quad,$
$f(0)=0<f(x’’_n)=\dfrac1{4n^2\pi^2}=f(0)+\varepsilon_n\leqslant f(0)+\varepsilon_n\;\;.$
Consequently, $\;\;x’_n\not\in X_{\varepsilon_n}\;,\;\;x’’_n\in X_{\varepsilon_n}\;.$
Since $\;0\in X_{\varepsilon_n}\;,\;x’_n\not\in X_{\varepsilon_n}\;,\;x’’_n\in X_{\varepsilon_n}\;$ and $\;0<x’_n<x’’_n\;,\;$ it follows that $\;X_{\varepsilon_n}\;$ is not connected.
Hence, in general, it is not true that $X_\epsilon$ is connected.
