Is the preimage of all sufficiently small neighborhoods of $\min(f)$ connected if the minimizer is unique?
Let $I$ be a compact interval and $f:I\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function with a unique minimizer. Is it true that the preimages of all sufficiently small neighborhoods of $\min(f)$ in $\mathbb R$ are connected and hence intervals containing $\operatorname{argmin}(f)$?
The question arose in the discussion of this question.

No, consider $f(x) := x^2(2 + \sin(1/x))$ on the interval $I := [-1, 1]$.  This function is set up to oscillate between $y = x^2$ and $y = 3x^2$ infinitely many times as $x \to 0$.  Now, if you take an $\varepsilon$ slightly larger than one of the local minima of the function, then the inverse image of $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ contains a small interval around that local minimum input, as well as a separate open neighborhood of 0, so that inverse image is not connected.
(If somebody wants to edit this with a nice display of the graph, feel free.  What I did locally was to run gnuplot with set samples 1000; plot[x=-0.2:0.2][y=0:0.06] x*x*(2+sin(1/x)),x*x,3*x*x .)
